# Delete documents from full elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Backstory: I have a single node Elasticsearch cluster, which was rapidly flooded with nonsense data, and hit the maximum index size of 2147483519.

Attempting to delete the extraneous records to recover the instance, has proven difficult.

`curl -XDELETE '$HOST:9200/$INDEX/_doc/$ID`

Returns the following

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "number of documents in the index cannot exceed 2147483519"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "number of documents in the index cannot exceed 2147483519"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Is there any way to recover this index? I also attempted a `_delete_by_query` with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of no. of doc ES can store is at shard level.
Therefore each primary shard can hold 2^31 docs. In your case probably all the requests are rejected post hitting the limit.
The best way currently is to create a new index with more no. of primary shard and delete the older index.

Also just a suggestion, check ILM of ES, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your entire index is containing the garbage data its better to delete the entire index using the [delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html).

Or if you have daily snapshot configured for your index, you can restore the index before you started getting the garbage data.

ILM for this case is not required, its more useful when you want to cleanup resources based on some policies and rule and not for one-off case.